# How to use HTML files in a ReactJS web app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications

I am currently learning to build web apps with React JS. How would you typically handle the HTML / JS splitting? Would you normally just have a "app" container in the HTML of every page and render a "app" component into it in the javascripts and manage everything from there? Or would you split up the HTML more, e.g. with toolbar, side menu and main view containers?

Answer (score 0):

Better it is to decompose your react app into components .
App container, toolbar, side-menu, header, footer, list view and so on,
If you want to load a different page use react router

Comment: Ok so basically I shouldn't have one top-level react component, but instead three or four depending on my layout, right? Makes sense, but how can I communicate between those top-level components? Let's say, I have a side menu component and a main view component. If I press a button in the side menu, I want a function of the main view component to be called. How is this accomplished?